# The quicksort version with the assembly inline (GAS) doesn't work (

Tags: c++, assembly, quicksort, gnu-assembler, qsort

I had to write the quicksort algorithm on C++ with assembly inline and compare it with the code without assembly inline. It correctly builds and runs on clear C++, but seems it endlessly loops when it is on assembly. 
Please help me to find out what is going wrong with the inline. PLEASE VERY MUCH PLEASE!!!!!
It is GAS syntax on mac, xcode.

[Here is the code on c++ without the assembly inline and with on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VqUGjENj). And it accompanied with the same code below:

```
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp; }
```

c++ without assembly inline

```
void quicksort(int numbers[], int left, size_t right) {

if (left<right) {
    int i = left;
    int pivot=numbers[right];
     for (int j=left; j<right; j++) {
        if(numbers[j]<=pivot) {
            swap(numbers[i], numbers[j]);
            i++;
        }
     }

    swap(numbers[i], numbers[right]);

    quicksort(numbers, left, i-1);//, left);
    quicksort(numbers, i+1, right);//, i+1);
} }
```

c++ with assembly inline

```
void quicksort(int numbers[], int left, size_t right) {

if (left<right){
    int i = left;

    asm volatile (

                  "movl (%[numbers], %%rdx, 4), %%esi \n\t"

                  "movl %%ebx, %%ecx \n\t"
                  "for: \n\t"
                  "cmp %%edx, %%ecx \n\t"
                  "jge endfor \n\t"

                      "if: \n\t"
                      "movl (%[numbers], %%rcx, 4), %%edi \n\t"
                      "cmp %%esi, %%edi \n\t" 
                      "jg endif \n\t"

                          "movl (%[numbers], %%rax, 4), %%edi \n\t"
                          "movl (%[numbers], %%rcx, 4), %%esp \n\t"
                          "movl %%edi, (%[numbers], %%rcx, 4) \n\t"
                          "movl %%esp, (%[numbers], %%rax, 4) \n\t"


                          "incl %%eax \n\t" 

                        "endif: \n\t"

                  "incl %%ecx \n\t"
                  "jmp for \n\t"
                  "endfor: \n\t"

                  : "=b" (left), "=d" (right), "=a" (i)
                  : [numbers] "r" (numbers), "b" (left), "d" (right), "a" (i)
                  : "memory", "ecx", "esi", "esp", "edi"
                  );

    swap(numbers[i], numbers[right]);

    quicksort(numbers, left, i-1);//, left);
    quicksort(numbers, i+1, right);//, i+1);
} }
```

Comment: `ESP` is not a general purpose register.

Comment: Why on earth don't you just use `std::sort` and be done with it? If there's some *really good* reason why you are trying to do something else, you should tell us that reason. Otherwise this just looks like a waste of time that could be replaced with a single line of code.

Comment: I haven't even really looked at the code but one thing that stood out (besides _ESP_ as someone mentioned) is that `=` is **OUTPUT** only but our code treats b, d, a as input and output. Sounds like you really want to us `+` instead of `=`

Comment: @JesperJuhl sorry for not mentioning a reason. I got this task from my informatics' professor to pass the exam. And it is necessary to make it done exactly this way

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for the advice; but if i don't make this code working, I won't pass the exam. There're no other options))))

Comment: Unrelated: Looks like you are implementing Lomuto partition. If so, `if(numbers[j]<=pivot)` doesn't look quite right. It's normally implemented with `if(numbers[j]<pivot)` and the `swap` and `i++` appear to be reversed. I'd have to play with it a bit to see if the changes work, but they are unusual.

Comment: @Michael Petch accademia is largely irrelevant in the real world - in my experience.

Comment: industry also cares about what you KNOW, so understanding how `std::sort` works is nice bonus. Anyway, correctness of assembly code is never assessed by just running it and waiting for output, that may often lead to correct results by accidents (for your particular test input), while the code contains some major problems. Always use debugger + single-stepping over single instruction, reasoning whether it is what you did want + expect, and verify everything. And use smart test inputs to validate code also against things like empty input, 1-size input, max-size input, negative and/or same values

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm from Russia, I cannot even choose the president and you want me to choose my exam task  for a pity I must do it so.

Comment: Саша Хмелёв do what it takes to pass the course. That's highest job priority right now. Working in the real world is further down the road and at that point @JesperJuhl 's comments kick in.

Comment: @MichaelPetch apologies for misunderstanding

Comment: @Michael Petch You may think so, but it worked for me.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL so much. I didn't get how to fix exactly this code though. But I remade the qsort from scratch, and now it runs just fine.  @MichaelPetch your advices were very helpful <3